# Regex for safe SQL insert

Tags: sql-server, regex, vbscript

I have a vbscript that inserts some strings into a database.  Often, these strings have weird characters, quotes, apostrophes, ampersands, etc.  I am currently using the following string to replace all but certain characters, but it's replacing semicolons and some other stuff (including spaces) that I would ideally like to keep.  So I'm basically looking for the least restrictive regex that will still generate a sql safe string.

For what it's worth, the strings are Windows installed applications (as you would see in Add/Remove Programs).

```
Function CleanUp (input)
  Dim objRegExp, outputStr
  Set objRegExp = New Regexp

  objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
  objRegExp.Global = True
  objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9]).)+"
  outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(input, "-")

  objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
  outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "-")

  CleanUp = outputStr
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work great so far in my testing:

> objRegExp.Pattern = "[^\x20-\x26,^\x28-\x7E]" 'Space through &, skips ', then ( through ~

I didn't know you could specify a range of ascii values.  This covers everything between Space and ~, excluding a single quote (').

Comment: Put into production Friday and it successfully imported/updated 4500 devices this weekend.  The ones I checked all look great.

Answer (score 2):

Why does the string have to be SQL safe? Use parameters and be done with it. [Hack-Proofing Your Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580736.aspx)

Comment: This is to fix a legacy VB script with over 2,500 lines of code.  But thanks for your concern...